Is there an analytical solution to the distribution of a sum of observations drawn from a Frechet distribution?
Let $X_i$ be an iid draw from a Frechet distribution. Let $\alpha_i \in  \mathbb{R}$.
Is there an analytical expression of the distribution of $\alpha_1X_1 + \alpha_2X_2 + \alpha_3X_3$? That is, can I obtain a PDF/CDF of this sum? Or can it only be estimated using numerical solutions?
If possible, please do post any textbooks/papers that cover this issue. Thank you!

Yes, they are iid, i've updated the post to reflect that. Thanks for catching that

Even with very nice $\alpha_i,$ such as $\alpha_i=1,$ I strongly doubt an analytical solution exists.  This is based on a very long study of treatises on the subject, such as Whittaker & Watson, where I don't recall seeing any result remotely like it.  Obviously I could be wrong, but in your place I would start off directly by considering how best to compute the distribution numerically.

More weak evidence against an analytical solution: Mathematica cannot manage to solve the convolution even in the $\alpha_i=1$ case for even the simplest shape/scale/location parameters.

John P. Nolan's book "Univariate Stable Distributions" (Springer) gives only four families of stable distributions: Gaussian, Cauchy, Levy, and Stable Distributions (in 2 types).

Assuming $\alpha_i >0$ for all $i$, it would not be too difficult to prove that $Y:= \alpha_1 X_1 + \alpha_2 X_2 + \alpha_3 X_3$ is tail-equivalent to $\alpha X$ where $\alpha$ is the sum of $\alpha_i$ and $X$ has the distribution of the $X_i$.
